# OBJLoader 404 error

Tags: three.js, http-status-code-404, objloader

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

loader.load(
      '/Models/mi.obj',function (object) {
      scene.add(object);
      }
 );
```

error message

> three.min.js:639 GET http://localhost:55127/Models/mi.obj 404 (Not Found)

current situation
The obj file and the main page are separated by folders.

Comment: Did you start the server at one folder up from where `Models` resides ?

Comment: Does this count as a three.js question? Three.js is a webgl, rendering library, not http.

Comment: Resolved.
It was a web.config problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem -- can you describe what was fixed in the web.config to get it to run?